# Adding 2nd Step to Sharepoint workflow causes Error "failed on start (retrying)"

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I am designing a workflow in sharepoint designer to manage the approval process for an infopath form. I am using sharepoint server 2007. My sharepoint site already has a form library dedicated to the approval form and I have already attached my workflow to the form library. My problem is that when I try to add a second step to my custom workflow, I always get the error "failed on start (retrying)" in the workflow status column of the form library when I initiate a workflow on a form. If I use only one step in my workflow, however, I get no errors. So does anyone know why adding multiple steps to a workflow would cause this error? This is super frustrating. Thanks.

My workflow is as follows:

Can be started manually or automatically by creation of an item
Step 1

Conditions: None

Actions:(all actions in step 1 executed in parallel)

Send an email to several sharepoint groups

Email the creator of the item

set a field in the current item (called "Workflow Status") to the number 1

Same task is assigned to several sharepoint groups (same groups a referenced in the first action).

Step 2

Conditions:

If field in current item equals "yes"
Actions:

Set a field in the current (called "Workflow Satus") to the number 5
Conditions:

Else if field in current item equals "no"
Actions:

Set a field in the current (called "Workflow Satus") to the number 0

Assign task to the creator of the item.

Note: I would post a screenshot, but I just joined stack overflow. So I cannot post images yet :/

Edit: If anyone is wondering, I reposted this question because a similar one I made was moved to the sharepoint stack exchange site. However, this is very little activity on that site, so in the interests of getting some help, I reposted.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add to workflow logs the various inputs/outputs of the workflow variables at each step. I usually do this as a method of debugging. This will help to locate the error.